# Why does my Sapphire Crystal disappear when I purchase Catalyst the Protector?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm following [this build](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/singed-his-chemical-romance-ap-hp-99768). It says, first purchase a Sapphire Crystal, then a catalyst of protector. But then my Sapphire Crystal disappears. Why?

So I understand that a Catalyst = Sapphire + Ruby + some gold. Is that right? But what if I don't buy the Ruby, but only buy Sapphire and then Catalyst? Why does the Sapphire disappear then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sapphire Crystal is one of the ingredients for Catalyst. You can purchase the full recipe at any time, and it will automatically subtract the cost of materials you already own from the purchase price of the recipes and use those rather than new materials.

Comment: you mean it only subtracts the cost of saphire, but not ruby, since I don't own that?

Comment: @bizso09 Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way that items build together in League of Legends. More powerful items are built by obtaining the "ingredients" needed for them (in the case of Catalyst the Protector, the ingredients are a Sapphire Crystal and a Ruby Crystal) and a "recipe" cost (in this case, the recipe cost for Catalyst is 450g). When the more powerful item is purchased, the ingredients are "combined together" to make the new item, so they no longer appear in your inventory.

Comment: yes, but I don't have a ruby crystal, which is an ingredient :S

Comment: @bizso09 You can imagine it as the the game automatically purchasing the ruby for you and then combining both items into the catalyst. All this happens so fast it just looks like the sapphire crystal disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrades consume their components. If you buy a Sapphire, then a Ruby, then a Catalyst, you lose both the Sapphire and the Ruby, and a gain a Catalyst. On the other hand, if you have the cash you can skip straight to the Catalyst.

Upgraded items always *cost* more that their components, and always *do* more, so they're never a bad idea. It's picking which upgrades to take that's the trick.

Comment: what if I don't have a ruby?

Comment: The cost to buy an item includes the cost of any components you don't currently have.