# What rules are used to decide if a new item bought must replace an existing one?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my Sapphire Crystal disappear when I purchase Catalyst the Protector?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78049/why-does-my-sapphire-crystal-disappear-when-i-purchase-catalyst-the-protector)

This game gives you 6 inventory slots, but for me it's not clear what rules are used by the system to replace an existing item when I buy a new one.

For example if I already have 2 swords, buying a third one replaces one of the two  (I hope the game chooses the less powerful one...) instead of adding a third sword to the inventory. Makes sense, I guess.
However 2 swords with a dagger are allowed and for orbs I cannot even recognize a pattern.

So, how can I understand which item (if any) will be replaced when I buy new gear?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. Can you add complete item names (e.g. Long Sword, Brutalizer, Zeal, etc.)? It would help with identifying your problem.

Comment: Don't have access to the game right now. The problem is that when I access to the item shop and double-click on an item I want to buy, sometimes this item replaces an existing one in my intentory

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78049/why-does-my-sapphire-crystal-disappear-when-i-purchase-catalyst-the-protector) uses different items as its example, but I *think* its answer covers your question.

Comment: Ah I see, so maybe I'm "consuming" the items to get the new one (if this one has requirements). I have to check this...

Comment: It wouldn't explain the system *automatically* replacing the items as League of Legends doesn't function in that manner. However, if you're attempting to buy different items, it is possible that you are "consuming" one of the items. For example, buying a third Dagger wouldn't replace one of the two you already have. However, if you attempt to buy Zeal, it will replace one of your Daggers as Zeal's recipe is 1 Dagger + 1 Brawler's Glove + extra gold.

Comment: In any case, we need clarification on whether you are purchasing the *same* item each time or *different* items. That would be the difference between "status by design" and "bug".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not 'replace' an item in the game like you are describing but you are progressing through the tiers of the items. Higher tiered items are made up of lower tiered items. A good example of this that is easy to grasp are the boots. There are the simple pair of boots and then there are the Berserker's Greaves. In order to obtain the Berserker's Greaves you have to buy a dagger and the first tire boots. You can then spend a little bit more money and combine them into the boots.

From your point of view its this combination that is 'replacing' the previous items. It is actually consuming them as requirements.

Now you do not have to buy the bits and pieces in order to obtain the high tiered items one at a time. But the price of that item will be the summation of all the smaller components. This is why items will appear to change their value from time to time. If you have some of the requirement items in your inventory already then it will use them towards the new higher tiered item.

Hope this helps.